# Maintain Order of Output with RandomTimeOut ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, random

This code will output 1 to 5 in random order. However, we want this code to output in the sequential manner (1,2,3,4,5). I do have a solution which may not be the right way to approach this question. Need Thoughts or right solution.

```
'use strict';
const callback = function( result ){
    console.log(result);
};
const print = function( num ){
    for(let i =0 ; i < num ; i++){
        randomTimeout(i , callback);
    }
};
const randomTimeout = function( i , callback ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback('Processing '+ i);
    }, Math.random()*1000 );
};
print(5);
```

Solution:

```
'use strict';
const callback = function( result ){
    console.log(result);
    print(5);
};
let i = 1;
const print = function( num ){
    if(i<=num)
        randomTimeout( i++ , callback );
};
const randomTimeout = function( i , callback ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback('Processing '+ i);
    }, Math.random()*1000 );
};
print(5);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any restrictions? Do you have to use the given `randomTimeout` function without alterations, for example?

Comment: You can not change randomTimeout. Only thing you can edit is print and callback.

Comment: Not clear what you want. I understand that you want the results printed out sequentially, but do you want to start all the timeouts at the same time (as in your first approach), or sequentially (as in your second approach).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - Sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start the timeouts sequentially, the solution you posted in your answer should work fine. For `num = 5` you'll have a runtime of 2.5 seconds (on average).

If you want to start all the timeouts at the same time, you could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as in the example below. For `num = 5`, the runtime will be 0.5 seconds (on average).

```js
const randomTimeout = (i, callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback('Processing ' + i);
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
};

const print = (n, callback) => {
  const values = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, k) => k + 1);
  const promises = values.map(i => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    randomTimeout(i, resolve);
  }));
  
  Promise.all(promises).then(result => result.forEach(callback));
}

print(5, x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think this is the correct way to approach it.